# SQL Server CASE - WHEN - ELSE

Tags: sql-server, sum, case

I have 2 tables like this:

- Table `CT`: `Number`, `CtID`, `Date`, `CTIE`
- Table `VT`: `Number`, `VtID`, `Quantities`

And my code:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(CT.Date), MAX(CT.CtID), VT.VtID, 
    SUM(VT.Quantities) AS SumVT,
    CASE
        WHEN CT.CTIE = 0 THEN SUM(VT.Quantities) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS IMPORT,
    CASE 
        WHEN CT.CTIE = 1 THEN SUM(VT.Quantities) 
        ELSE 0 
    END AS EXPORT   
FROM 
    CT 
INNER JOIN 
    VT ON CT.Number = VT.Number
GROUP BY  
    VT.VtID, CT.CTIE
ORDER BY
    VT.VtID
```

This code works fine but the result is not what I want. With some `VtID` that have both `CTIE = 1` and `CTIE = 1`, SQL now returns 2 separate rows with same `VtID`, one for `CTIE = 0` and one for `CTIE = 1`. But I need it to display only 1 row for each `VtID` instead of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `CT.CTIE` in the group by and place your case statements inside the aggregate function

```
SElECT 
    MAX(CT.Date), MAX(CT.CtID), VT.VtID, SUM(VT.Quantities) AS SumVT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CT.CTIE = 0 THEN VT.Quantities ELSE 0 END) AS IMPORT,
    SUM(CASE WHEN CT.CTIE = 1 THEN VT.Quantities ELSE 0 END) AS EXPORT 
FROM CT INNER JOIN VT ON CT.Number=VT.Number
GROUP BY  VT.VtID
ORDER by VT.VtID
```

Comment: wow thank you for your help. BTW i have another version of this code if anyone want to learn :D


 `SELECT Temp.VTID, SUM(Temp.Import) AS Import, 
    SUM(Temp.Export) AS Export
 FROM (SELECT VTID, Quantities,
CASE WHEN CT.CTIE = 0 THEN Quantities ELSE 0 END AS Import,
CASE WHEN CT.CTIE = 1 THEN Quantities ELSE 0 END AS Export
FROM VT INNER JOIN CT ON CT.Number = VT. Number) AS Temp
 GROUP BY Temp.VTID.`